# What is the difference between epoll and multiple connect attempt?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, io

Let's say i have a non blocking TCP client socket. I want to connect to a TCP server. I found that either of the following ways can be used to do so.

```
int num_of_retry=5;
for(int i=0;i<num_of_retry;i++){
   connect(SOCKET_FD,...);
   sleep(1000ms);
}
```

and this

```
connect(SOCKET_FD,...);
epoll_wait(...,5000ms)
```

What are the main difference in the above two approaches, performance and otherwise?

Comment: Note you can epoll for more than one thing at a time

Comment: The difference here is that the first example won't work. You can't reconnect a TCP socket, even if the prior connect attempt failed. You have to close it and create a new one. That's what `epoll()` saved you from having to do. It also blocks for the correct amount of time, unlike your try/sleep/spin loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, the main difference is that `sleep()` will not exit until the full interval has elapsed, whereas `epoll()` (and `select()`, too) will exit sooner if the pending connect operation finishes before the full interval has elapsed.

Otherwise, both examples are blocking the calling thread until something happens (which kind of defeats the purpose of using a non-blocking socket - except that this approach is the only way to implement a timeout with `connect()`).

Note that in either example, if you call `connect()` on a socket while it is already working on connecting, `connect()` will fail with an `EALREADY` error. If a connect operation times out, you *should* `close()` the socket and create a new socket before calling `connect()` again.  And you *should* wait for `epoll()` (or `select()`) to tell you when the operation is finished, don't just call `connect()` in a loop until it reports something other than `EALREADY`.